# How do I solve "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime"?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

I've downgraded from python version 3.7 to python 3.6.8 using windows 10.0, Tensorflow-gpu, cuda 9.0, cudnn 7.0. 
Executed the command as shown in code below in order to train my data.
The error I got was: "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime".

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

I expected that "TensorFlow will initialize the training and that the training will begin".

Actual Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 47, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update cuDNN  (>= 7.2).

Comment: Hi, I will try to uninstall the current cuDNN 7.0 and install >=7.2 to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to match the tensorflow version with the CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

try updating tensorflow

try this := `pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow`

worked for me!